# Android: How to get reference to listView?

Tags: android

I am trying to use a `MapView` in conjunction with a `ListView`. My understanding is that I need to extend `MapActivity` and then get a reference to the `ListView` to be used in my class. My problem is that I cannot get a reference to the `ListView`.

This is my XML:

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="268dp"
        android:layout_y="151dp" >

    </ListView>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

This is how I am trying to get a reference to the `ListView`:

```
//instance vars
ListView listView;

//get ref to listview
listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
```

For some reason it says that list is not a field. Am I referencing it incorrectly?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

However, since you're not using a `ListActivity`, you don't *have* to put `"@android:id/list"`. `"@+id/list"` (or anything custom) will work.

Usually, you use the Android ids when required, such as when using a `ListActivity`/`ListFragment` which can only function if your custom layouts contain the proper ids.

Also, you should be using `MapFragments/SupportMapFragment`s instead since [MapActivity is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview).